# Dataframe with a dictionary column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (Name of worker and Job Details) the job details column are dictionaries with different name each one depending of the job. An example of this dictionaries:

```
{'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department': 'Quality'}}...............
{'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'department': 'Sports'}}
```

In this dataframe, I would like to extract for example all the rows that contains Engineer in the name of the dataframe of the column Job Details.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks!!

Comment: What did you try? what format does the desired output have?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following dataframe as example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Mary', 'Peter', 'Susan', 'Linda', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John', 'Paul'],
                     'Job Details': [{'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department': 'Quality'}},
                                        {'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'department': 'Sports'}},
                                        {'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'department': 'Sports'}}]})


[Out]:
     Name                                        Job Details
0    John  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
1    Mary  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
2   Peter  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
3   Susan  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
4   Linda  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
5    Paul  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
6  George  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
7   Ringo  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
8    John  {'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'dep...
9    Paul  {'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'dep...
```

Then, to obtain the rows where `Job Details` contain the word `Engineer` one can do the following

```
df_engineer = df[df['Job Details'].apply(lambda x: 'Engineer' in x)]

[Out]:
     Name                                        Job Details
0    John  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
1    Mary  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
2   Peter  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
3   Susan  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
4   Linda  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
5    Paul  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
6  George  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Oracle', 'department...
7   Ringo  {'Engineer': {'company': 'Google', 'department...
```

If one wants only the rows that contain `Periodist`, then

```
df_periodist = df[df['Job Details'].apply(lambda x: 'Periodist' in x)]

[Out]:
   Name                                        Job Details
8  John  {'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'dep...
9  Paul  {'Periodist': {'company': 'Goal to Goal', 'dep...
```

---

**Note:**

- There are now various adjustments one can make, depending on the desired output format, such as resetting the index (for example, for `df_periodist`, one way woulb be like `df_periodist.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`), and more.